# Растяжение декалей Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть декали, свои и Decal Projector от юнитеков с URP. На угловатых поверхностях декали сильно растягиваются и наши и юнитековские

[image: Примерно так]

Лечится это дело поворотами, проблема динамически задать нужный. Пробовал брать нормаль и задавать по тому же направлению, и пробовал брать все нормали, которых касается объект, и находить средний вектор из них (Работает крайне медленно)

```
private GameObject CreateSticker(Transform parentSticker, Vector3 positionSticker, Vector3 directionSticker)
    {
        _lastSticker = Instantiate(_sticker);

        _lastSticker.transform.position = positionSticker;
        _lastSticker.transform.parent = parentSticker;
        //_lastSticker.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.forward, directionSticker); по 1 нормали
        
        _lastSticker.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(CheckMiddleAngles(_stickerContacts.pointNormals)); // из множества нормалей

        return _lastSticker;
    }

    private Vector3 CheckMiddleAngles(List<Vector3> normalPoints) //средний вектор из n векторов
    {
        Vector3 middleAngle = Vector3.zero;

        for(int i = 0; i < normalPoints.Count; i++)
            middleAngle += normalPoints[i];
                    
        middleAngle /= normalPoints.Count;

        return middleAngle;
    }
```

Есть ли хорошее и **производительное** решение для такой проблемы? В какую сторону копать?

Comment: Вопрос в том, бля чего. Если маленькие пулевые декали, то можно не заморачиваясь по нормали точки хита, огрехов, даже грубых, никто не заметит. Если же нужен довольно крупный след от взрыва, это уже другой разговор.

Comment: Крупный след. С маленькими, естественно, проблем нет, их как раз никто и не заметит :)
Пока в архив закинул эту задачку, как сяду - решение пульну сюда, или кто-другой пульнет

Comment: Крупный след на сложной геометрии c `Projector` точно не сделать, это ведь эффект сделанный с помощью дополнительной камеры, не возможно учесть топологию, тупо плоский clip space. Подобные эффекты делаются исключительно с помощью шейдера.